# How to turn vsynch ON for secondary display?

Tags: graphics-card, external-display, hdtv

I've just got myself a new computer (Acer Aspire 7600U AIO) and I've just plugged it in to my TV (LG55620T) on the AIOs HDMI-out-port to mirror the screen so I can play games and watch movies on the bigger screen. But unfortunately I cannot seem to find any setting for turning vsynch on for the secondary display. I cannot find any setting for vsynch at all but it's definitely turned on for the primary screen, and not for the secondary. Which is too bad because it's very annoying with all image-tearing while playing movies and games. Does anybody know if it's possible somehow to turn this on for both displays?

The computer has two graphics adapters, Intel HD Graphics 4000 and NVIDIA GeForce GT 640M. I'm not sure if they are both used at the same time for different displays or if the NVIDIA-card only is activated when playing games. But I can't find any setting for vsynch on either settings-menues (Intel or NVIDIA). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Vsync is usually an application setting. In games, do you have it turned on?

If you haven't tried installing the latest NVidia drivers, I suggest trying that, then going into the NVidia control panel (NOT the Windows resolution/Personalize control panels) and check that your TV appears there; and tweak settings for the TV display (e.g. refresh rate, resolution, scaling).